# JMETER : While condition is failing with syntax error

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario where in I need to wait for the response text  .I need to send the same request till i get the required response text. I included my http samples in while loop with a counter. Now I am not able get the correct while condition.
Tried with below conditions.

${__javaScript(("${recordTypeLabel1}"!="asdf" && ${counter} < 5),)} 
${__jexl3("${recordTypeLabel1}" != "asdf",)} 
Both are failing. How to handle this? 
Pleasae help.

```
Threadgroup     
Once only controller Login 
loop controller  
            HTTP req 
            HTTP req 
            While loop {
            Counter 
            HTTP request
            HTTP Request 
               JSON extractor 
            }
           HTTP req  
Once only Controller Logout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for the [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) would be:

```
${__jexl3("${recordTypeLabel1}" != "asdf" && ${__jm__While Controller__idx} < 5,)}
```

Don't use __javascript() function as it is some form of a performance anti-pattern, stick to __jexl3() or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) functions if you need to script some extra logic

Also you don't need to introduce a Counter, since [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5/) you have a special pre-defined variable called `${__jm__While Controller__idx}` which holds zero-based iteration number of the While Controller. (If you change the While Controller's label to something else - make sure to amend the variable accordingly)

1. Exit when loop number exceeds the threshold

   [image]
2. Exit when variable value becomes expected:

   [image]

Comment: Thankyou !. This worked.I am getting error in command prompt like this. "================================================================================
Uncaught Exception java.lang.StackOverflowError in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-1,6,main]. See log file for details. where do we get the log file? in bin folder i dont have jmeter.log file.From the GUI I am seeing at the botton of the screen. Is that the only log file? any other log file available .please help